# create table with foreign key column, AutoNumber primary key column, and default values for dates

Tags: java, jackcess

I need to create a table using Jackcess library which consists of foreign key reference column and primary key column with auto increment. Also, how can I specify default values for all the columns like Date/Timestamps?

In the [Jackcess cookbook](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/cookbook.html),
I found one example to create table but it is not covering the above cases.

How can I implement the above?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks and other chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), should never be included in a question.

Comment: you should be able to do everything except the foreign key reference.  at this point in time, jackcess does not support creating foreign key indexes.

Comment: as of the 2.1.5 release of jackcess, you can create foreign key references.

Answer (score 2):

**Creating Relationships**

Jackcess 2.1.5 added the ability to create Relationships (and hence Foreign Key Constraints) using `RelationshipBuilder`, e.g.

```java
// example in the JavaDoc for RelationshipBuilder:
//
Relationship rel = new RelationshipBuilder("FromTable", "ToTable")
     .addColumns("ID", "FK_ID")
     .setReferentialIntegrity()
     .setCascadeDeletes()
     .toRelationship(db);
```

**Other Items**

- Creating a table with an AutoNumber field:

As shown in the [cookbook](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/cookbook.html), that is done using `ColumnBuilder#setAutonumber(true)`.

- Setting a default value for a field:

That can be done by creating a new Property named "DefaultValue" for the column:

```java
Table tbl = db.getTable("Donations");
Column col = tbl.getColumn("DonationDate");
PropertyMap pm = col.getProperties();
pm.put("DefaultValue", "Date()");
pm.save();
```

Note, however, that while this default value will be used by ACE/Jet and [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), Jackcess *itself* does not currently respect the "DefaultValue" property when it adds new rows to a table.

Comment: Update to this answer, as of 2.2.0 release, jackcess supports optional evaluation of expressions (e.g. default values).  the functionality is still in beta, so it defaults to disabled.  you can enable it with a system property or by setting a property on the database instance.